# Verilog simulation unexpected behaviour in a simple mux design (Using EDAPlayground and EPWave)

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, multiplexer, system-verilog

I am experimenting with EDAPlayground, and I have created a simple structural module that should take the MSBs from one input and merge it with the LSBs of the other and vice versa, using 2 input multiplexers.
Here is the `.sv` code:

```
module mux2(input logic [3:0] d0, [3:0]  d1, s,
            output logic [3:0] y);

    assign y = s ? d1 : d0;
  
endmodule

module mux2_8(input logic [7:0] d0, [7:0]  d1, s,
              output logic [7:0] y);
  
  mux2 muxHigh(d0[7:4],d1[7:4],s,y[7:4]);
  mux2 muxLow(d0[3:0],d1[3:0],~s,y[3:0]);
  
endmodule
```

And here is the testbench:

```
module testBench();
  
  logic[7:0] tbD0;
  logic[7:0] tbD1;
  logic tbS;
  logic[7:0] tbY;
  
  mux2_8  MuxDUT(tbD0,tbD1,tbS,tbY);
  
  initial begin
    
    #1;
    tbD0='b10101111;
    tbD1='b11110101;
    tbS=1;
    
    #1;
    tbS=0;
    
    #1;
    tbS=1;
    
    #1;
    tbD0=0;
    $finish();
 
  end
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
  end
  
endmodule
```

When `s` is 0, I get the expected output: MSB from `d0` and LSB from `d1` (10100101). But, when `s` changes to 1, the output becomes `d1` (11110101). The correct result should be 11111111 when `s`=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mux2_8`, you mistakenly declared the `s` input port as 8 bits wide, but you really want it to be 1-bit wide.  In the following line:

```
module mux2_8(input logic [7:0] d0, [7:0]  d1, s,
```

the second range specifier, `[7:0]`, applies to all signals after it: `d1` and `s`.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.2.2.3 *Rules for determining port kind, data type, and direction*:

> For subsequent ports in an ANSI style port list:
> — If the direction, port kind and data type are all omitted, then they shall be inherited
> from the previous port.

One way to fix this problem is to add the `input` keyword just before `s`:

```
module mux2_8(input logic [7:0] d0, [7:0]  d1, input s,
```

The same problem occurs with the `mux2` module.  Change it to:

```
module mux2(input logic [3:0] d0, [3:0]  d1, input s,
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
module mux2(input logic [3:0] d0, [3:0]  d1, input s,
            output logic [3:0] y);

    assign y = s ? d1 : d0;
  
endmodule

module mux2_8(input logic [7:0] d0, [7:0]  d1, input s,
              output logic [7:0] y);
  
  mux2 muxHigh(d0[7:4],d1[7:4], s,y[7:4]);
  mux2 muxLow (d0[3:0],d1[3:0],~s,y[3:0]);
  
endmodule
```

When I run your code on [EDAPlayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/ayDc), I see warning messages that directly point to these signal width mismatches.  I see messages on 4 different simulators.  For example:

```
Warning-[PCWM-W] Port connection width mismatch
testbench.sv, 24
"mux2_8 MuxDUT(tbD0, tbD1, tbS, tbY);"
  The following 1-bit expression is connected to 8-bit port "s" of module 
  "mux2_8", instance "MuxDUT".
  Expression: tbS
  Instantiated module defined at: "testbench.sv", 8
  Use +lint=PCWM for more details.
```

Another visual clue that there was a problem was that the signal showed up as `s[3:0]` in the waveforms of the `muxHigh` instance.